# Show file info in last finder column

Tags: finder, metadata

Before 10.14 the last finder column always showed filesize, date modified etc. by default.

In the new version this information is blocked by the useless "more" button.

Is there a way to have this information always visible with the default finder window size?

Before 10.14
[image: See here]

After 10.14
[image: see here]

Comment: In addition to Redarm's answer, when **[√] Show Quick Actions** is checked, the info you don't see is there and scrollable or if the window is appropriately sized for it, it's a non issue.

Comment: It’s not a non-issue, it’s a damn nuisance, & I didn’t know where the switch was either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the preview settings in Finder for each of the various kinds of documents via the **View > Show Preview Options** menu.

Just un-tick the "Show Quick Actions" option for text files (see top of window) to get rid of the Quick Actions toolbar in the preview area.

[image]

Comment: I looked for something like that but didn't find it. +1